# How do I add an item that contains a comma to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an array of objects that I am looping through. I need to create an array that contains items in the format LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME.

When I do this I end up with an array of lastname, firstname, lastname, firstname  etc. because it interprets my comma in the text as a separator for two array values.

JSON (example):

```
[
   {"lastname":"Levy","firstname":"Robert"},
   {"lastname":"Johannenson","firstname":"Svenn"},
   {"lastname":"Smith","firstname":"Albertson"}
]
```

then

```
$authors = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($index); ++$i) {
```

$at = trim($index[$i]->lastname) . ", " . trim($index[$i]->firstname);
        $authors[] = $at;
    }

Then $authors contains

```
["Levy","Robert","Johannenson","Svenn","Smith","Albertson"]
```

instead of the desired:

```
["Levy, Robert","Johannenson, Svenn","Smith, Albertson"]
```

I'm really not new to this but this has me stumped. I could try some kind of character replacement after the array is made (e.g. using | as a separator then doing a str_replace or something) but am looking for a more elegant way.

Comment: `$authors` certainly does not contain exactly that. How exactly are you getting that output?

Comment: `because it interprets my comma in the text as a separator for two array values` - inside a string? then your JSON parser is badly broken.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://eval.in/169154  It does not " interpret [your] comma in the text as a separator for two array values".  How are you viewing `$authors`?  Where are you seeing these results?

Comment: Which 'comma in the text' ? I don't see any on the example you've shown.

Comment: it's because you are telling it to. . ", " tells it to break the value for lastname with a comma, then give the value for first name.

Comment: I am seeing the result in Charles as I watch the data returned from the PHP page encoded as JSON.

Comment: The PHP code you show here does *not* generate the results you claim.  Where are you encoding `$authors` as JSON?  Perhaps the error is elsewhere.  For a simple check, what does `echo count($authors);` show you?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: I do apologize. The error is in fact elsewhere. PHP is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Check the way you parse the result back to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example

```
$index = json_decode('[
   {"lastname":"Levy","firstname":"Robert"},
   {"lastname":"Johannenson","firstname":"Svenn"},
   {"lastname":"Smith","firstname":"Albertson"}
 ]');
$authors = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($index); ++$i){
    $at = trim($index[$i]->lastname) . ", " . trim($index[$i]->firstname);
    $authors[] = $at;
}
```

and here is the output of $authors

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Levy, Robert"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "Johannenson, Svenn"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Smith, Albertson"
}
```

So everything seems to be correct.

Can you provide full source code?

Answer (score 0):

The result is parsed further on in the script and was causing the output to break. PHP is working as it should. Thanks for all the quick answers.